# Pythonic way of making a dict from a string

Tags: python, list, dictionary, split

I have this code which takes the a string output and converts it into a dict, it works but I wonder if there is a better way particularly with regard to splitting the string as its a bit clunky.

**Code**

```
string = "Position = 1009.82391102873, Height = 8.3161791611302, Weight = 0.650591370984836"

def string_to_dict(string): 
    mydict = {}
    temp_list = list(string.split(","))
    big_list = []
    for item in temp_list:
        item_split_list = list(item.split(" = "))
        big_list.append(item_split_list)
        mydict[item_split_list[0]] = item_split_list[1]     
    return mydict 

mydict = string_to_dict(string)
print(mydict)
print(type(mydict))
```

**Returns**

```
{'Position': '1009.82391102873', ' Height': '8.3161791611302', ' Weight': '0.650591370984836'}
<class 'dict'>
```

Comment: You split by `,`, then by `=`, you `strip()` and in the end you should have keys and values. Basically you did everything except the strip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in one line:

```py
dct = dict(s.split('=') for s in string.replace(' ', '').split(','))
```

But if you want the values to be `float`:

```py
dct = {k: float(v) for s in string.replace(' ', '').split(',') for k, v in [s.split('=')]}
```

Outcome:

```py
>>> dct
{'Position': 1009.82391102873, 'Height': 8.3161791611302, 'Weight': 0.650591370984836}
```

Comment: You code seems to work, but in the sense of The Zen of Python that is only one part of the job. It is not easy to read and Readability counts.

Comment: this won't work if the key or value has white space in them.

Comment: @KlausD.: what part do you consider to be opaque or hard to read? Seems eminently readable and straightforward to me.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenating could help a little bit maybe.

[input]

```
keys = [x.split('=')[0].strip() for x in string.split(',')]
arg = [x.split('=')[1].strip() for x in string.split(',')]
new_dict = dict(zip(keys, arg))
```

[output]

```
new_dict
{'Position ': ' 1009.82391102873',
 ' Height ': ' 8.3161791611302',
 ' Weight ': ' 0.650591370984836'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
temp_list = list(string.split(","))

new_dict = {temp_list[i].split("=")[0].strip():temp_list[i].split("=")[1].strip()}
```

It's a little weird but it works and its more "pythonic"

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner:

```
dict(kv.replace(" ", "").split("=") for kv in string.split(","))
```

which gives

```
{'Position': '1009.82391102873',
 'Height': '8.3161791611302',
 'Weight': '0.650591370984836'}
```

That line first splits the original string by `,` to separate the string into a list of `"key = value"`. The whitespace in those strings is removed to get strings like `"key=value"`, and then those strings are split by `=` to get a list like `[["key1", "value1"], ["key2", "value2"]]`. Because those lists are all length 2, we can pass it to `dict` to construct a dictionary.

As @VishalSingh comments, this will not work if keys or values have white space.

Comment: this won't work if the key or value has white space in them.

Comment: @VishalSingh - sure but the OP's string doesn't have whitespace

Answer (score 1):

you can use dictionary comprehension to create a new dictionary.

```
your_dict = {
    pair.split("=")[0].strip(): pair.split("=")[1].strip()
    for pair in string.split(",")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the beauty of the exercice, the shortest form I could think of is:

```
>>> eval(f"dict({string})")
{'Position': 1009.82391102873, 'Height': 8.3161791611302, 'Weight': 0.650591370984836}
```

or without f-strings

```
>>> eval("dict({})".format(string))
{'Position': 1009.82391102873, 'Height': 8.3161791611302, 'Weight': 0.650591370984836}
```

However, given the reading difficulty, I would not say this is the best pythonic way

Comment: It is beautiful though, if the code were just for me to read I would go with it, thank you MarcoP.